# How to find the hex of a string in a pdf

Tags: pdf, reverse-engineering, pdfbox, file-format

I created a simple pdf with nothing but the digit 5 in it. I then opened the pdf in hex-workshop and tried to make sense of the .pdf format to find the bytes responsible for the '5' showing in the pdf, and see if I can change them to turn it into a 6. As it turns out, the .pdf format is quite complicated and I got lost. Can someone point me as to where I should look in the hex, or what to change, and how is "FlateDecoded" related to my question, if at all?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is far too broad.

Comment: @usr2564301 instead of doing so, which is far from helping me with my question, maybe you have a suggestion on how to improve it?

Comment: The PDF file format is way more complicated than you think. The full reference is at http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf -- it's a hefty 1309 pages of text.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot see a way to improve this question which would make it less broad. Unwittingly, you are asking for quite a lot here. Download that reference and you'll see.

Comment: The PDF specification is about 1000 pages. And then there is about 1000 pages for the font formats, and much more. FlateDecoded is the Flate compression. And PDF is not really made for editing. To see some structure of PDF, see your PDF in PDFDebugger. Or ask Raul: https://github.com/firstlookmedia/sidtoday/blob/master/documents/2004/2004-12-09_SIDToday_-_Ask_Raul_PDF_Files.pdf

Comment: I know there are lots of objects in a pdf's body. I was hoping to at least zoom in on how to identify a text object...assuming *that* is whether the actual text would be written in some form. Thanks anyway

Comment: The problem is that PDF isn't something like HTML where you can understand it somewhat just by looking at the binary. There is the cross-reference stuff, the compression, the content stream operators, the font encoding, and much more.

Comment: @felisimo *"a suggestion on how to improve it"* - the only way I see you could improve it is by sharing the PDF you generated and asking to *illustrate where in **this specific PDF** there are the instructions to draw that '5'*. With an answer to that you can then turn to the PDF specification and read up on the related concepts. By the way, *to turn it into a 6* you may have to embed a different font, often fonts embedded in PDFs only contain those glyphs actually needed, i.e. your document probably only contains a font with only the glyph for '5', in particular no glyph for '6'.